# Properly implementing comparable and generics

Tags: java, generics

I am struggling to understand how to implement generics and comparable into my code. I am tasked with converting the method below to proper generic methods. I also need to switch out the parameters with proper generics.

```
public static String min(String a, String b) {
    if (a < b)
         return a;
    else
         return b;
}
    
public static String max(String a, String b) {
    if (a < b)
         return b;
    else
         return a;
}
```

And this is my attempt

```
public static <AnyType> min(<AnyType> a, <AnyType> b) {
    if (a < b)
         return a;
    else
         return b;
}
    
public static <AnyType> max(<AnyType> a, <AnyType> b) {
    if (a < b)
         return b;
    else
         return a;
}
```

Comment: Uh, `String` is a reference type, so you can't really use `<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=` relational operators.  You should get a compiler error for the "original" code you are trying to convert. The same will apply to `<AnyType>`.

Comment: You're right. I didn't know about the anytype one though. I'll try that and see what happens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to ensure that `AnyType` is comparable.

```
public static <AnyType extends Comparable<AnyType>> AnyType min(AnyType a, AnyType b) {
    return a.compareTo(b) < 0 ? a : b;
}

public static <AnyType extends Comparable<AnyType>> AnyType max(AnyType a, AnyType b) {
    return a.compareTo(b) > 0 ? a : b;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not going to be able to write a single `compareTo` method that will work for any type. But, you can write a `min` and `max` that will work on any type that properly `implements Comparable`.

[Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html) is a Java [interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html). It has a method `compareTo`, which contains no code. Using it *requires* a `compareTo` method be implemented for each class that uses it.

Use of the `Comparable` interface looks something like this:

```
 public class Foo implements Comparable<Foo> {
```

That requires, somewhere in class Foo, this:

```
     public int compareTo (Foo someFoo) { ... }
```

Where `...` is replaced by code specific to `Foo`.

Then, a class that needs to compare two variables of type `Foo` might have code like this:

```
  Foo bar = new Foo();
  Foo bin = new Foo();
  ...
  if (bar.compareTo(bin) < 0) { ...
```

If there were another class that `implements Comparable`, that class would also need a `compareTo` method specific to that class.

You could write generic `min` and `max` methods that would work on several classes, *as long as those classes implement `Comparable`*. The `<T extends Comparable<T>>` enforces that.

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T min (T a, T b) {
    if (a.compareTo(b) <= 0) return a;
    return b;
}
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T max (T a, T b) {
    if (a.compareTo(b) >= 0) return a;
    return b;
}
```

However, generics are not necessary in this case. Java allows the name of an interface to be used as a type:

```
public static Comparable min (Comparable a, Comparable b) {
    if (a.compareTo(b) <= 0) return a;
    return b;
}
public static Comparable max (Comparable a, Comparable b) {
    if (a.compareTo(b) >= 0) return a;
    return b;
}
```